# How can I enable shell-command in Termux build of Emacs?

Tags: shell-command, termux

Installation of emacs on termux (from f-droid) does not support shell-command. Does this require a port of shell access code to termux, or is it some sort of option that I would be able to activate?

Comment: I have Emacs28.1 in f-droid termux and `M-x shell-command` is running just fine.